# Passing the "owner"-identity to the create-view for a related model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have this viewmodel for `Employees`:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // some more properties
    public List<EmployeeReservationViewModel> Reservations { get; set; }
}
```

... and this one for `EmployeeReservations`:

```
public class EmployeeReservationViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    // some more properties
    public EmployeeViewModel Employee { get; set; }
}
```

In the `Employees` `Details`-view, I have a link for adding a new `EmployeeReservation`, like this:

```
<a asp-controller="EmployeeReservations" 
   asp-action="Create">Add reservation</a>
```

How should I pass the `EmployeeId` to the `EmployeeReservations/Create`-View?

At the moment I'm using a session-variable, like this, in the `Employees`'s Details-method in the controller:

```
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("EmployeeId", employee.Id);
```

... and then retreiving it in the Create POST-method in the `EmployeeReservations`-controller:

```
employeeReservation.EmployeeId = HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("EmployeeId").Value;
db.Add(employeeReservation);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I have a feeling my method is not optimal. What if the session times out? Is there another, more fail-safe method of doing it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  asp-route-id

In view

```
<a asp-controller="EmployeeReservations" 
   asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="10">Add reservation</a>
```

In Controller add id as parameter fore create action

```
Public IActionResult Create(string id){
}
```

Comment: I have to add this in the `Create`-view to make that work: `<input type="hidden" name="EmployeeId" value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]" />`. Am I right? Because I tested it, and it works. But it seems a bit "hacky" to have to add manual hidden inputs in the view.

Comment: You can use it like this but good practice is passing the employee id in a model to view from create controller

Comment: It worked when I added: `EmployeeReservationViewModel vm = new EmployeeReservationViewModel { EmployeeId = id }; return View(vm);` in the create GET method and `<input type="hidden" asp-for="EmployeeId" />` in the create-view. :)